# 2 wattmeter method for measurement of power in 3 phase AC circuits

Tags: three-phase, wattmeter

Could someone please explain the concept of the lagging and leading pf in 3 phase AC circuits with respect to these special conditions

[image: Some Special Cases]

Comment: Do you know what lagging a leading means in terms of a single phase circuit?

Comment: Yes i know inductive components make it lag and capacitive components make pf leading

Comment: Do you know what the phase angle is between line voltage and phase current in a 3-phase system with a purely resistive and balanced load? Also take note of what I linked you on your earlier question.